# Javascript url rewriter

Tags: javascript, regex, url-rewriting

I would like to make an url rewriter in javascript, my problem is that if i make something like:

```
var str='/test/service-34.htm',
    exp='/test/service-[0-9]*.htm';
console.log(str.match(exp));
```

I would get '/test/service-34.htm' as response, so if i can't make a replace like:

```
/test/service-34.htm -> test.php?service=$1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
"/test/service-34.htm".replace(
  /\/test\/service\-([0-9]+)\.htm/
, "test.php?service=$1"
);
```

It is important to create a [backreference](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html)  to use the `[0-9]` part in your replacement. Also you might want to use `+` instead of `*` to make the number required.

Comment: Missing * :P WORKING PERFECT, ty.
System doesnt allow me to mark this anwser as solved, 4min to be able.